# Assert issue when executed with a selenium test

Tags: java, selenium, junit, webdriver

I have the following class:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

 public class ClasseTeste extends Navegadores {

  public static void verificarTitulo() {
     abrirChrome();
     String titulo = driver.getTitle();
     assertTrue(titulo.contains("google"));
     fecharNavegador(); 
  }

}
```

When I execute a main method

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
     verificarTitulo();     
}
```

This exception happens:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/Assert
at test.NovoProjeto.ClasseTeste.verificarTitulo(ClasseTeste.java:11)
at test.NovoProjeto.Main.main(Main.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.Assert
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 2 more
```

I'm trying create some simple tests for a selenium webdriver.

Comment: This link will likely help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.Assert
```

means that you need `junit.jar` to be on your classpath when you run your tests.

Comment: I'm using maven to manage my dependencies, do i really need junit.jar for this?

Answer (score 0):

as you are using maven as build manager add the following dependencies in `POM.xml`  file:

```
             <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                 <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                 <version>2.41.0</version>
             </dependency>

             <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                 <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
                 <version>2.41.0</version>
             </dependency>



             <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.10</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
```

and in code your import will look like:

```
import junit.framework.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
```

Hope this works for you.